# jquery accordion menu open middle on page load

Tags: jquery, accordion, onload

I have a simple accordion drop down menu that has four main levels.  I can get the first one to open on page load and the last one to open on page load.  What I would like is to get the third one to open on page load.
Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="CSS/Accordion1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Accordion1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="primary">Employee Web Links:</div>
        <div class="secondary">
            SharePoint Webpart
            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->

            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->
        </div>
        <div class="primary">Phone Directory:</div>
        <div class="secondary">
            Sharepoint Webpart
            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->

            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->
        </div>
        <div class="primary">Web Search:</div>
        <div class="secondary">
            Sharepoint Webpart
            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->

            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->
        </div>
        <div class="primary">Industry News:</div>
        <div class="secondary">
            SharePoint Webpart
            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->

            <!--Place Code Between these Markers-->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my jquery code:

```
$(function () {

    $(".accordion .secondary").hide();//hides containers
    $("div.accordion .secondary:last").slideDown('fast');//opens last container on load
    $(".accordion .primary").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".accordion .secondary").slideToggle("fast");
    })
})
```

In the forth line of the code I can change the ".secondary:last" to ".secondary:first" and that will open the first accordion menu.  But I would like to have the third accordion menu open on load.  I have tried ".secondary:third" and ".secondary:2" but those do not work.  Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to select the index of the element using ":eq()". the following will select the third matched element on a zero based index.

```
$("div.accordion .secondary:eq(2)").slideDown('fast');
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a champ.  Thank you Da Rod!